# How to get internet from WiFi and share to LAN router

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, internet-sharing

I have a `Cisco 877` Router (plus a 16 port Switch) managing my Office LAN where 10+ PCs and Network printers are connected. I need a LAN because I run an Apache server with some web apps (accessed  only locally).

Unfortunately, I don't have any DSL connection available. The only access to the Internet is from a WiFi router placed in another floor of the building.

I also have a `TP-Link TL-WA830RE` Range Repeater and a `D-Link DWL-2200AP` Wifi Access Point.

Is it possible to get Internet access from WiFi and then share it to all PCs through the LAN?

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you already have Internet access via WiFi.  Can you clarify what's missing in your setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The networking concept you're looking for is a [bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_%28networking%29); a bridge connects two communications networks into one network.

You should be able to configure your D-Link access point as a wireless bridge. According to the [D-Link support page](http://12.130.207.110/us/en/support/faq/access-points-and-range-extenders/access-points/dwl-series/dwl-2200ap/how-do-i-configure-two-dwl-2200ap-in-bridge-mode), your access point should be able to run in "PtP Bridge" mode, which does exactly that. [I quote](http://support.dlink.com/emulators/dwl2200ap/html/help_adv.html):

> This selection allows the DWL-2200AP to connect to another wireless
>   Access Point capable of bridging. However, be aware that most
>   manufacturers use proprietary settings when enabling bridging mode in
>   the Access Point. A typical scenario for this selection is connecting
>   two buildings through a wireless connection. Enter the MAC address of
>   the remote bridge to which the AP will associate.

An alternative is to install [DD WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) and you can follow [this setup guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged). Although in your case, the D-Link should be able to do this without custom firmware.

Your networking topology should look like this:

- The external access point is wirelessly connected to your D-Link access point, providing internet access.
- Your D-Link access point provides this access via a regular LAN port (the WAN port will be kept unused). You should connect the D-Link LAN port to your switch. Make sure your D-Link LAN ip address has an ip address in your subnet (either by static configuration or by DHCP server).

Comment: Should i then connect to the Router via Ethernet Cable to the WAN port or on normal LAN port?

Comment: Added target networking topology in the answer.

Comment: @kofm if this solution works for you, it's considered polite to accept the answer. Also, it automaticaly marks your question as closed.